# Using ArcGIS java script API in local host

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am new to ArcGIS javascript API and I want to use it in local host mode.
I definitely follow Esri support instruction for using of it. but unfortunately i can not load it.

What do I write instead of `[HOSTNAME_AND_PATH_TO_JSAPI]` in `init.js` and `dojo.js` host when I want to use this library in local host mode?

replacement `->` `localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.16/3.16/`

Answer (score 1):

When you say you want to use it in local host mode what do you mean?  Are you just running the application from localhost?  Perhaps you should still just require the files from the CDN.

Something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dojoConfig = {
        async: true,
        parseOnLoad: false,
        packages: [
            {
                name: "application",
                location: "/App/js"
            }
        ]
    };
</script>
<script defer src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.19/"></script>
<script defer src="~/App/app.js"></script>
```

If you actually have the ArcGIS API local, and you want to access those files local, then just change the path from CDN path above to local path.

Answer (score 1):

Depnding on the version hosted in your local server , in your case Ithink you've just missed to remove also `dojo` from the path

In 3.XX you have to replace :

`[HOSTNAME_AND_PATH_TO_JSAPI]dojo` by `-->` `localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.16/3.16/`

in both `init.js` and `dojo.js`